# Search and replace with the same string pattern using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a file with many link like this

```
http://hust.se.vtio.owl#...-fashion-shop
```

In ... is the different name like abc, def, blah blah....
How can i use regular expression to find all links and replace to

```
http://hust.se.vtio.owl#...-fashion-shop-place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:`(http:\/\/.*)-`

Replace by :`$1` or `\1`